# where clause in inner join does not work

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql query:

```
select count(tu.authorID) as c,t.tweettext,tu.name 
from tweet t 
inner join tweet_user tu on t.authorid=tu.authorid 
where count(tu.authorID)>=5;
```

but it seems that inner join does not work with where in this case and I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function 0.062 sec
```

Does anyone know what is my problem or how I can do that?

Comment: What is being counted here? The absence of a `GROUP BY` means this query would probably not return the correct results even if the limiting clause were correctly specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` for aggregate function like `COUNT`:

```
 SELECT t.tweettext,tu.name, count(tu.authorID) as c 
 FROM tweet t inner join tweet_user tu on t.authorid=tu.authorid 
 HAVING count(tu.authorID)>=5
```

Although `mySQL` could do away with `GROUP BY` you could probably include `GROUP BY` also but I think you don't need the `tweettext`?

```
 SELECT tu.name, count(tu.authorID) as c 
 FROM tweet t inner join tweet_user tu on t.authorid=tu.authorid 
 GROUP BY tu.name
 HAVING count(tu.authorID)>=5
```

Answer (score 1):

For group clauses you need to use

```
GROUP BY x
HAVING COUNT(x) > 0
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp